# Prove that $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}→\mathbb{R}$ is affine if and only if it is convex and concave

Tags: convex-analysis, solution-verification, convex-geometry

I would like you to evaluate the following proof that $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is affine if and only if its convex and concave:

From the convexity of f we have for $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\lambda \in [0,1] f(\lambda x_1+ (1−\lambda)x_2)\leq\lambda f(x_1)+(1 - \lambda)f(x_2)$
and for concavity we have $f(\lambda x_1+ (1−\lambda)x_2)\geq\lambda f(x_1)+(1 - \lambda)f(x_2)$

Thus it follows that f convex and concave is $f(\lambda x_1+(1−\lambda)x_2)=\lambda f(x_1)+(1 - \lambda)f(x_2)$

And F is affine if $f(x)=ax+b$

Going:
$$
f(\lambda x_1+ (1−\lambda)x_2)=\lambda f(x_1)+(1 - \lambda)f(x_2)=\lambda (ax_1+b)+(1-\lambda)(ax_2+b)=\lambda ax_1+\lambda b+ax_2-\lambda ax_2+b-\lambda b=a(\lambda x_1+x_2-\lambda x_2)+b=a(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)+b
$$

Back:
$$
f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2)=a(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)+b=a(\lambda x_1+x_2-\lambda x_2)+b=\lambda ax_1+ax_2-\lambda ax_2+b=\lambda ax_1+ax_2-\lambda ax_2+b+\lambda b-\lambda b=\lambda(ax_1+b)+(1-\lambda)(ax_2+b)=\lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2)
$$

Comment: Just a couple of things to make it easier to read: "$x_i$" is x_i; "$\leq$" is \leq, and "$\geq$" is \geq.  Using $=>$ might be understood as "implies."

Comment: I didn't get where you proved the following fact: If $f$ satisfies $f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2)$ for each $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ and each $\lambda\in [0,1]$, then $f$ can be written as $f(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Was it supposed to be the 'Going' or 'Back' part?